# Displaying change in moving average on map

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to show the change in moving average by county on a map.

Currently, I have the calculated field for this:

```
IF ISNULL(LOOKUP(SUM([Covid Count]),-14)) THEN NULL ELSE
WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Covid Count]), -7, 0)-WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Covid Count]), -14, -7)
END
```

This works in creating a line graph where I filter the dates to only include 15 consecutive dates. This results in one point with the correct change in average.

I would like this to number to be plotted on a map but it says there are just null values.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is only one part of defining a table calculation (a class of calculations performed client side tableau taking the aggregate query results returned from the data source)

Equally critical are the dimensions in play on the view to determine the level of detail of the query, and the instructions you provide to tell Tableau how to slice up or layout the query results before applying the table calc formula. This critical step is known as setting the “partitioning and addressing” for the table calc, sometimes also as setting the “compute using”. Read about it in the online help for table calcs. You can experiment with using the Edit Table Calc dialog by clicking on the corresponding pill.

In short, you probably have to a dimension, such as your Date field to some shelf - likely the detail shelf, and the set the partitioning and addressing, probably to partition by county and address by state.

If you have more than a couple of weeks of data, then you’ll get multiple marks per county. You may need to decide how to handle that on your map.